# Trusted Custom mold manufacturers for confections

Tags: baking, equipment, candy, mold, jelly

Hello Seasoned advice community,

I am new here and just want to say thanks for letting me into your lovely community. =)

I am the R&D manager at a confections company and I am in need of some Custom molds for my jelly products. I've sourced some molds from a company in France and went through the whole back an forth process with them to nail down a design for my molds. They sent me numerous pictures of the mold, as well as, sample products they made using my molds and everything looked great. I received the first set of molds yesterday and they are nothing like the pictures! =( I'm working with them to hopefully rectify the situation but needless to say this will be the last time I use them.

Does anyone know of a trusted and reliable custom mold manufacturer?

Comment: When you say 'jelly' do you mean gummi type candies?  Because if I remember correctly from an episode of 'How it's Made' or similar show, they used positives and pushed it into corn starch, then poured the gelatin mixture into that.  (of course, this was a production line process ... it might just be they were doing it because that's how they could automate it easier)

Comment: When I say jelly I mean a gummi type candy made using pectin. We have looked into starch molding systems but decided it wasn't for us, its a long messy process that needs a large curing room to be used correctly. I am looking for Silicon molds specifically but and open to metal or hard plastic mold.

Comment: Well, another possibly messy process would be making your own molds (but it only needs to be done once) -- http://www.makeyourownmolds.com/

Comment: We have secured a local mold manufacture!!! Thank you to all who responded!

Comment: if they work out for you, you should come back and submit it as an answer.  (you're allowed to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 1):

I found a local mold manufacture who can produce exactly what we need in a timely manner. The folks over at Acme Apothecary have saved the day!

Support local business! =)
Thanks again to all who commented and thanks to the people at stack exchange for making this all possible.